# iPad App name & splashscreen is different on the simulator as the iPad device

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios-simulator, splash-screen

I couldn't find any results in google, so i hope someone has a solution for my problem:

I changed the name, App icon, "splashscreen image" of an existing app in xcode and all of them are shown correctly on the ipad simulator 4.3

If I start the app on my ipad iOS 4.3.5 the App icon is changed but the text under the App icon and the splashscreen is the old one. How is this possible? 
There aren't any images of the old splashscreen in the project folder.
I deleted the old App from the iPad. Restarted the iPad several times with no luck.

Comment: In the products folder of your project inside Xcode, right click -> find target of the .app file and open it in Finder, then go back up a few folders so you're in a folder called DerivedData. Delete the folder containing the current build of your project. Then rebuild and redeploy.

Comment: Checklist:
-Removed DerivedData
-Deleted the App from iPad
-Cleaned the Build
-Capitalization checked

Comment: -Default-Landscape~ipad.png & Default-Portrait~ipad.png is there
-App is not universal
-CFBundleDisplayName is set

Answer (score 1):

Delete that app from your device.  (long hold of icon and then hit the X)
Connect to Xcode
Clean
The build and run on your device.

The resources on the device are probably lingering and not being replaced when you rebuild it.

Answer (score 0):

This link gives detailed information about launch images

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BuildTimeConfiguration/BuildTimeConfiguration.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW11

For your situation you'll need is a file called Default-Landscape~ipad.png in your bundle if your app universal.

Was your app iPhone/iPod specific before?

To change the name of your app, try adding a key to your Info.plist called CFBundleDisplayName~iPad with the name you want. I'm not certain this will work mind.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, images that work fine in the simulator but not on the device are caused by capitalization problems. The simulator won't be case sensitive, but the device will be. Check the filename against how you refer to it in code (and/or the standard names that you need to use, e.g. "Default.png" with an uppercase D) and make sure both match.

A Clean and rebuild might also help.